# EXT.NET Accessing ComboBox value at server DirectEvent

Tags: model-view-controller, combobox, ext.net, formpanel

I have Ext.Net MVC form that post values to DirectAction. On server side, In DirectAction CoboBox selected value is always null.

```
public ActionResult Save()
{
var cmbSender = this.GetCmp<ComboBox>("cmbSender");
var senderID = cmbSender.SelectedItem.Value;
}
```

I have checked

```
Request["cmbSender"]
```

but it does not work

```
<form id="form12">
@(
X.TabPanel()
    .Items(
        X.FormPanel()
        .Title("New Job")
        .ID("pnlNewJob")
        .Layout(LayoutType.Form)
        .MarginSpec("5 5 5 5")
        .Items(

X.Panel()
                                    .Border(false)
                                    .ColumnWidth(0.4)
                                    .Layout(LayoutType.Form)
                                    .Items(
                                        Html.X().ComboBox()
                                        .ID("cmbSender")
                                        .DisplayField("Code")
                                        .ValueField("ID")
                                        .EmptyText("Code")
)
</form>
```

Comment: Try to set the clientIdMode property as static for combobox

Comment: Do you see "cmbSender" in a request's parameters? Also I don't see where/how you call the Save action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use X.FormPanel()'s .Buttons()  to post your form data. Add your ComboBox selected value Button's DirectEvent. An example :

`.Buttons(
         Html.X().Button()
                 .Text(AppTexts.Save) 
                 .Icon(Icon.Accept)
                 .ID("SaveButton")
                 .DirectEvents(de => 
{ 
de.Click.Url = Url.Action("Save");                                                                                                                       de.Click.ExtraParams.Add( new Parameter 
                            { 
                              Name = "cmbSelectedValue", 
                              Value ="App.cmbSender.getValue()", 
                              Mode = ParameterMode.Raw 
                            }
);
})
)`